# How to resolve service with AutoFac from type of a variable

Tags: c#, xamarin, autofac, typeof, resolve

I have a class with method

```
public Task ServiceResolver(ILifetimeScope scope, IViewModel viewModel)
{
 Type type = viewModel.GetType();
 scope.Resolve<type>();
}
```

Is it possible to resolve the service similar to that using GetType or typeof(), this doesn't work but I think if there is other option.

Or maybe there is another better way to resolve services outside the class. The problem is I have multiple viewModels and if I want to use inside viewModel other Resolved viewModel inside I have to refer to AutoFac container or resolve all of them before start of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the type directly to `Resolve`:

```cs
public Task ServiceResolver(ILifetimeScope scope, IViewModel viewModel)
{
 Type type = viewModel.GetType();
 var resolvedInstance = (IViewModel)scope.Resolve(type);
}
```

That overload of `Resolve` returns `object`, so you will want to cast it before you use it.